# how to store multiple instances of dyn Trait, where Trait has associated types?

Tags: rust, trait-objects, dynamic-dispatch

I'm learning rust, and a project idea I had was to write a command line parsing framework, that enables the use of commands and options. I have previously done this same project in other languages.

I have defined my option struct as such:

```rust
pub struct Arg<T: FromStr> {
    // fields
}
```

In a command, I wish to store multiple Arg instances, that may have different generic types. To do this, I resorted to creating a non-generic trait for `Arg<T>`, to then store them as `dyn Argument`s.

```rust
pub trait Argument {
    type Target: FromStr;
    type ParseError;

    // other trait members ...
}
```

This trait is implemented for `Arg<T>` as such:

```rust
impl<T: FromStr> Argument for Arg<T> {
    type Target = T;
    type ParseError = T::Err;

    // other members ...
}
```

And inside my Command struct, I wished to store Argument instances like this:

```rust
pub struct Command {
    args: Vec<Box<dyn Argument<Target = dyn Any, ParseError = dyn Any>>>
}
```

This compiles so far. However, when I have an actual `Arg<T>` instance, I can't seem to cast them to `dyn Argument<Target = dyn Any, ParseError = dyn Any>`. I realize this approach is flawed for multiple reasons, but I can't find a working solution that would enable the behaviour I'm looking for.

Is there a way to implement this behaviour?

Comment: It's hard to say because you haven't given enough information in your question (such as the signature of the trait's function members) but generally if you want to do this you need a second "type-erased" trait that has all of the types erased by `dyn` versions instead.

Comment: `Arg<T>` does not implement `Argument<Target = dyn Any, ParseError = dyn Any>>`. Even if `T` is `dyn Any` (which would be a requirement), `T::Err` would also need to be `dyn Any`. These requirements (but especially the second one) seem unlikely because `dyn Any` is unsized.

Comment: Further,  you can't "fix" it by using `Target = dyn FromStr` instead because `FromStr` is not object-safe.

Comment: The usual pattern for creating a set of commands is to use an enum instead.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you want to do is be able to create a template for how to parse one argument and put several in a vector. To do this, the template should not be something like `Box<dyn Argument>`, it should be something like `Box<dyn ArgumentBuilder>`.

Furthermore, the error should probably not be `Box<dyn Any>`, it should be `Box<dyn ErrorTrait>` where `ErrorTrait` defines what you should be able to do with an error. For example, an error should probably implement `std::error::Error`.

Here is a proof of concept ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5fbcaff7e59dce8ef127e6293c80967d)):

```rust
use core::marker::PhantomData;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::str::FromStr;

/// A parsed arguemnt
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Arg<T>
where
    T: Debug,
{
    data: T,
    // other fields
}

/// The trait an `Arg` thing implements (to be abe to put it in a dyn)
pub trait Argument: Debug {
    // other trait members ...
}

impl<T> Argument for Arg<T> where T: Debug {}

/// The thing which creates an `Arg`
pub struct ArgConstructor<T>
where
    T: FromStr + Debug + 'static,
    T::Err: ParsingError,
{
    _t: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> ArgConstructor<T>
where
    T: FromStr + Debug + 'static,
    T::Err: ParsingError,
{
    /// A constructor for easier usage
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { _t: PhantomData }
    }
}

// Put additional traits you want your errors to implement here
/// The trait errors should implement
pub trait ParsingError: std::error::Error {}

// implement the error trait for all errors for which it is possible
impl<E: std::error::Error> ParsingError for E {}

pub trait ArgumentConstructor {
    fn from_str(&self, s: &str) -> Result<Box<dyn Argument>, Box<dyn ParsingError>>;
}

/// The trait an `ArgConstructor` implements (to be able to put it in a dyn)
impl<T> ArgumentConstructor for ArgConstructor<T>
where
    T: FromStr + Debug + 'static,
    T::Err: ParsingError,
{
    fn from_str(&self, s: &str) -> Result<Box<dyn Argument>, Box<dyn ParsingError>> {
        match T::from_str(s) {
            Ok(a) => Ok(Box::new(Arg { data: a })),
            Err(a) => Err(Box::new(a)),
        }
    }
}

pub struct Command {
    args: Vec<Box<dyn ArgumentConstructor>>,
}

fn main() {
    let command = Command {
        args: vec![
            Box::new(ArgConstructor::<u8>::new()),
            Box::new(ArgConstructor::<i32>::new()),
        ],
    };
    let strings = ["3", "-10"];
    let out: Vec<Box<dyn Argument>> = strings
        .iter()
        .zip(command.args.iter())
        .map(|(s, p)| p.from_str(s).unwrap())
        .collect();
    dbg!(out);
}
```